# Circle from $n$-gon Area${}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, circles, pi, polygons

To gain more intuitive nature about the irrational and transcendental behavior of $\pi$ circles were constructed with $n$-gons circumference $C=1$ see [[SE]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4036641/650339).

This method however describes how a circle (I think) can be created from $n$-gons with area: $A=1$.

While I am no math expert I would like to know if the method is valid. I cannot find a similar method on internet for reference.

Polygons with $n$ sides ($n$-gons) can be defined as function of the side length $s$ and the angle between $3$ neighbor edge points. The $n$-gons are defined such that one edge point is in the origin.

$$x=s \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{p} \cos \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)$$
$$y=s \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{p}  \sin \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)$$

Normally summing $p=n$ elements completing one pass $360^{\circ}$. The area of all $n$-gons is set to $A=1$. The side length $s$ can be determined with $n$-gon area formula [[Wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon):

$$A=\frac{ns^{2}}{4 \cdot \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}=1$$
$$s=2 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{ \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}{n}  }$$

Resulting in the following $n$-gons:

$$x=2 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{ \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}{n}  } \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{p} \cos \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)$$
$$y=2 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{ \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}{n}  } \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{p}  \sin \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)$$

Empirical (see graphs) it is found that $n$ and $k$ could be continuous numbers, though not sure if that is valid hence the question. By integration a circle formula is found:

$$x=2 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{ \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}{n}  } \cdot \int \cos \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)dk=\frac{n}{\pi}\cdot  \sqrt{ \frac{ \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}{n}  } \cdot  \sin \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)$$
$$y=2 \cdot \sqrt{ \frac{ \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}{n}  } \cdot \int  \sin \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)dk=-\frac{n}{\pi}\cdot  \sqrt{ \frac{ \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)}{n}  } \cdot  \cos \left(\frac{2k+1}{n}  \pi \right)$$

This parametrized function gives us a circle if the radius $R$ of the circle exists [[Wolfram]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20n*sqrt%28tan%28pi%2Fn%29%2Fn%29%2Fpi%20n%20to%20infinity):

$$R_{\infty}=  \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}   \sqrt{ n  \cdot \tan \left(  \frac{\pi}{n} \right)  }  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

The radius seems to exist in infinity. We set the area of the $n$-gons $A=1$ the area of the final circle becomes:

$$A=\pi R^{2}=\pi \cdot \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \right)^{2}=\frac{\pi}{\pi}=1$$

Here the final circle has the same area as the $n$-gons.

#### Question [Edit].

While I am no math expert I would like to know if the method is valid and where it needs correction. I cannot find a similar method on internet for reference.

I am having difficulties swapping discrete $n$ and $k$ for continuity. More information about continuity in this context is welcome.

With circle creation $n$-gon area $A=1$ the found radius $R_{\infty}=1/\sqrt{\pi}$ is a limit value. Circle creation $n$-gon circumference $C=1$ [[SE]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4036641/650339), the radius $R=1/{2 \pi}$ is better defined (no limit value). Why is a circle with $C=1$ better defined as $A=1$?

Could a similar method also be scaled up to $3d$ with polyhedron's. (Platonic solid's)? First thought it is not possible while the numbers of edges grow irregular. Ideas are welcome.

#### Graph 1: $n$-gons discrete and continuous.

(x and y swapped so graph is landscape)
[image]

#### Graph 2: Intuition for integration.

(x and y swapped so graph is landscape)
[image]

Comment: Can you please make it clear what your exact question is?

Comment: @Benjamin Wang, rephrased question. Is discrete to continuous transformation valid (integration). Is it allowed and by what? How to interpret radius transcendental?

Comment: There is no need to resort to integrals. Using the de Moivre's formula for convenience,

$$x+iy=\sum_{k=0}^p e^{i(2k+1)\pi/n}=e^{i\pi/n}\sum_{k=0}^p e^{i2k\pi/n}=e^{i\pi/n}\frac{1-e^{i2(p+1)\pi/n}}{1-e^{i2\pi/n}}.$$

For $p=n-1$, this is $0$, and for $p=n$, it is $e^{i\pi/n}$, which tends to $1$.